# select2 and Pjax not work together in yii2

Tags: widget, yii2, jquery-select2, pjax

when i use pjax in yii2. selec2 widget stops working. while select2 working alone. (not working together)

im using select2 widgets and pjax together. but when submit form with pjax. in new form, select2 not work. (just show loading img). pls help me
what is problem?

I want to use both at the same time.

[select2 extention page](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2)

Answer (score -1):

in view:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Hrml;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Vitrin */

?>

<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?php
if($model->getProductTypeSetting()=='both')
{
    echo $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

in _form:

```
<!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->
<?= Html::beginForm(['vitrin/index', 'id' => $id], 'post'['data-pjax' => '']); ?>
<?= Html::activeInput('text', $model, 'name', ['class' => $username]) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'submit']) ?>
<?= Html::endForm() ?>
<!-- END PAGE CONTENT-->
```

in controller:

```
if(Yii::$app->request->post('productType'))
{
$model->productType = $_POST['productType'];
if($model->productType=='physical')
{
return $this->renderAjax('_formProduct', ['products' => $this->getProductName()]);
}
else
throw new \yii\web\HttpException(406, Yii::t('app', 'Your request is invalid.'));
}
```

in _formProduct:

```
<!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->
<?= Html::beginForm(['vitrin/index', 'id' => $id], 'post', ['data-pjax' => '']); ?>
<?php
echo Select2::widget([
'name' => 'name',
'data' => [1 => "First", 2 => "Second", 3 => "Third", 4 => "Fourth", 5 => "Fifth"],
'options' => [
 'placeholder' => 'Select a type ...',
 ],
 ]);
 ?>
 <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'submit']) ?>
 <?= Html::endForm() ?>
 <!-- END PAGE CONTENT-->
```

and AppAssets class:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
public $basePath = '@webroot/themes/backend';
public $baseUrl = '@web/themes/backend/assets_t';
public $css = [
'bootstrap-rtl/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css',
'bootstrap-rtl/css/bootstrap-responsive-rtl.min.css',
'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
'fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css',
'uniform/css/uniform.default.css',
];
public $js = [
'bootstrap-rtl/js/bootstrap.min.js',
'js/jquery.blockui.js',
'uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js',
];
```

when submit _form with pjax. in _formProduct, select2 not work. (just show loading img).

**Generally**, when I use Pjax, other Js codes are deactivated.

Comment: No solution? Generally, when I use Pjax, other Js codes are deactivated.

Answer (score -1):

In your view header:

```
use kartik\select2\Select2Asset;

Select2Asset::register($this);
```

Also make sure you have the latest Select2 widget.